# Prove that $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

> Let $X$ be the comb space given by
> $$
> \begin{align}
> X ={} &\bigl\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 
> 0 \leq y \leq 1 \text{ and } (x=0 \text{ or } x=\tfrac{1}{n}  \text{  for some} \in \mathbb{N} \bigr\} \\
> &\cup \bigl\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid 
> y=0 \text{ and } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \bigr\}.
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Let the set $A$ be given by $A = \{(0,1)\}$.
> Prove that  $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$.

**My attempt**: Define the map $F:X \times [0,1] \to X$ given by
$$ 
F(x,y,t) = \bigl( x, (1-t)y \bigr)
$$
is continuous and satisfies $F(x,y,0) = (x,y),\, F(x,y,1)=(x,0)$.

After that, I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Your map is not continuous, I don't think. It is sort of tearing downwards whilst keeping $(0,1)$ fixed. Also, just glancing at the links on the right hand side of the page, you *can't* strongly deformation retract $X$ onto $(0,1)$, merely weakly deformation retract it, so your map $F$ couldn't work

Comment: Sketch some pictures, like storyboarding an animation. As in the first comment, you need to construct a sequence of retractions, then chain them all together. If it's easier just parametrize each for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, and then you can "speed up" the retractions when you stitch them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your homotopy $F$ is a good start. It deforms $X$ to $X' = [0,1] \times \{0\}$ and keeps $X'$ fixed. Next deform $X'$ to $X'' = \{(0,0)\}$. This is possible with a homotopy keeping $X''$ fixed. With a final homotopy move $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$. Composing these three homotopies yields a homotopy from $id_X$ to the constant map $c(x) = (0,1)$.

Note that $A$ is not a [strong deformation retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)#Deformation_retract_and_strong_deformation_retract) of $X$.

$A$ being a deformation retract of $X$ means that $id_X$ is homotopic to a retraction of $X$ to $A$; one does not require that there exists a homotopy keeping $A$ fixed.

As we have seen, $X''$ is a strong deformation retract of $X$. This means in particular that $X$ is contractible to the point $(0,0)$. It is well-known that a contractible space is contractible to each of its points (the method to prove this is the same in the third step above).